# How can I achieve shelving in git similar to perforce?

Tags: git, automation, gitlab, perforce

The team is switching from Perforce to Gitlab. As a part of the process, we noticed that git supposedly has a disadvantage of shelving files which Perforce does effectively.

Say I am working on a feature and I want to share a few files with a teammate.
In Perforce, I'd just shelve the files and share the CL number, which my teammate can unshelve and view.

In git, I need to create a branch, add the files, commit them and push to origin. The teammate(s) then need to checkout the branch, pull changes and view. That's a lot of steps.

How do I automate this to a single command? Essentially I'm looking to create a command called `git shelve` which can

1. Create a new branch, add the files from staging area to the branch, commit the files, push them and return the name of the branch to the user after the process is finished(or throw error if any step fails).

  a. Optionally, give the user to choice the name of the branch

2. Another user runs the command `git unshelve <branch name>`. This checks out the branch, pulls the latest changes and displays the file names which were changed.

  a. Optionally, give the user an option to delete the branch if the unshelve operation is successful

So essentially I want to achieve the effect of `git stash` and `git stash pop`, but want the latter to be run on my teammate's machine.

Please help me achieve this automation. Can this be done by writing bash scripts, which are installed on respective machines?

Comment: Creating a new branch, making the changes, committing and then pushing is probably the most canonical Git way of doing this.  And it's less effort than you might think.  You _could_ try to git stash, which in fact makes a commit under the hood.  But it might not be worth the effort to go that route.

Comment: While it may be the right way to do things, I'm looking for a quicker solution. The team is acquainted with the perforce way of shelving, sharing the CL, and unshelving to view changes. I want to make a git solution as close to this as possible.

Comment: You're going in the wrong direction.  Your team should learn how to use Git.  Perforce is really only superior as a VC tool in the case of persisting large files, such as multimedia.  For source code, use Git, and use it the way it is intended.

Comment: I get it Tim. Git is better than Perforce as a VC tool, the reason for transition. The team also likes it. But this feature stood out when we brainstormed. Shelving, sharing, unshelving is very common in the team. Hence, the need for automation.

Comment: Your requirements sound like a reasonably simple shell script. If you write it, name it `git-shelve`, and place it in your `$PATH`, you could run `git shelve` as you desire. Have you tried writing it yet?

Comment: I've never used Perforce, but shelving sounds like it's just automating the branch/push step on the creation end. Replace "CL number" with "branch name", and unshelving just sounds like a pull/checkout operation.

Comment: You could have a couple of simple aliases for what you call shelve and unshelve. With tags or branches for the shelve part, and something like `git show <refspec>:<path>` for the unshelve part. A branchname (or tagname) would just replace the reference role your CL had.

Comment: @larsks I haven't written shell scripts in my life. I know what it is, so a random idea it can perhaps be done by scripting. It's not scalable though. So before writing any script, I was seeking other ways to achieve the same. For instance, if I could just modify a central place(maybe install a package on server), then all teams can benefit from it.

Comment: @chepner It's a bit different. The files which are shelved can be dragged and dropped, the CL number is auto generated. So manual effort is much lower.

Comment: @Romain Valeri Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Git likes naming things. The program could (1) auto-generate a tag name based on millisecond timestamp (2) stage all (3) commit (4) push (5) copy the SHA1 of the commit to your clipboard (6) you send that SHA1 manually. The tag name is irrelevant. It’s just so that you have something to push. They on the other side fetch all tags and get to check out that SHA1 (commit).

Comment: This probably doesn't help with gitlab, but when I used Phabricator at a previous job, `arc diff` struck me as being a nicer version of `p4 shelve` (nicer because it was also integrated with CI): https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/arcanist_diff/  It seems like it's not a difficult sort of thing to build on top of git; all the building blocks are there.

Comment: @Guildenstern How do I write the program? Do I use shell scripting and install in different systems manually? Is there a sample you can share from which I can get some idea?
Thanks!

Comment: It's folly to think that you're going to make your life easier by learning shell scripting (which by the way is really quite unintuitive), distributing an application, and supporting its use, rather than using the git primitives.  I know you don't want to hear this but I thought it bore repeating.

Answer (score 0):

Git likes to name things.[1] You can’t push around commits (to my
knowledge) without giving things names first. But you can automate the
name-giving and in turn make any commit shareable without having to
worry about names.

1. Make a ref namespace for throwaway names, for example `refs/tags/throwaway/`
2. Use that to “stash” all your current changes to tracked files
3. Copy the SHA1 (the “change list”) that the command outputs
4. Give it to the other person
5. They fetch your changes by fetch *all* tags
6. Now that they have all tags your commit is reachable
7. They check out your commit

`git-shelve`:

```
#!/bin/sh

# git-shelve

current_branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) &&
# Don’t let the next commit affect your branch
git checkout --detach &&
# Commit all modified tracked files
git commit --all &&
rev=$(git rev-parse HEAD) &&
unique=$(uuid) &&
git tag throwaway/$unique &&
git push origin throwaway/$unique &&
# Back to where you were
git checkout $current_branch &&
# Print the name of the commit so that you can give it to your coworkers
printf "\n$rev\n"
```

`git-unshelve`:

```
#!/bin/sh

# git-unshelve

set -u

# The SHA1 printed by git-shelve
arg1="$1"

git fetch --tags &&
# May fail if working tree is not clean
git checkout $arg1
```

#### A boring disclaimer

This is a very non-standard workflow.

#### Notes

1. [From](https://gregoryszorc.com/blog/2017/12/11/high-level-problems-with-git-and-how-to-fix-them/):

   > As I said, my Mercurial workflow doesn't rely on naming
   > things. Unlike Git, Mercurial's store has an explicit (not shared)
   > storage location for commits (changesets in Mercurial
   > parlance). And this data structure is ordered, meaning a changeset
   > later always occurs after its parent/predecessor. This means that
   > Mercurial can open a single file/index to quickly find all
   > changesets. Because Mercurial doesn't need pointers to commits of
   > relevance, names aren't required.

   My lack of experience with other VCS means that I cannot speak about
   my own experiences here.